# Create friendly URL with multiple rewrite rules?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /school/courses/more-courses/courses-type/coursedetails/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule [^/]+ index.php [QSA,L]
```

So php is used to replace the /coursedetails/ part with the course name e.g. /school/courses/more-courses/courses-type/cooking/, and so the script above will redirect everything that doesn't exist to index.php.

What I want to do is create a friendly URL to map, for example, /school/courses/more-courses/courses-type/cooking/ to /school/courses/cooking/

Is this possible by adding an additional rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/school/courses/more-courses/courses-type/cooking/$ /school/courses/cooking/ [R,L]
```

Comment: Seems to be a lot of work considering the number of courses that might be available/change (assuming that it is not a school set up by Gordon Ramsay)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
RewriteBase ^/school/courses/([a-z\-]+/){1,5}$
```

This allows you to have any URL while begins with `/school/courses/` and then anything (1-5 times) in the pattern `folder-name/`. Now, in your bootstrap (index.php) you can get the request URI and process the action accordingly.